# JavaScript Switch statement with multiple cases

Tags: javascript

I have to find an object from an array of objects if the object is found then I have to add sort property to it, if it is not found then I am looking for another object.
but if all the objects are present then I have to add sort property to first match only.
I am using the switch case to achieve this. but if all the objects are present the sort property is added to all the objects. could anyone please tell me how can I achieve this?

Below is my code.

```
this.columns = this.columns.map(field) => {
            delete field.id;
            switch (field.name) {
                case 'creationTime':
                    field.sort = 'asc';
                    break;
                case 'priority':
                    field.sort = 'asc';
                    break;
                case 'completionTime':
                    field.sort = 'asc';
                    break;
            }
            return field;
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by this _**but if all the objects are present then I have to add sort property to first match only**_

Comment: @RifatBinReza means if all the three cases are matched  i have to add sort property to ist case

Comment: Then you cannot assign the column right away. You have to loop through the array to find if all three matches are there first

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.
Add a variable 'match' and assign it a value 'false'.
Than wrapp the switch with a condition which check's if match isn't true.
If one object matches than the variable is reassigned to 'true'.

```
let match = false;

this.columns = this.columns.map(field) => {
  delete field.id;
  if (!match) {
    switch (field.name) {
       case 'creationTime':
          field.sort = 'asc';
          match = true;
          break;
       case 'priority':
          field.sort = 'asc';
          match = true;
          break;
       case 'completionTime':
          field.sort = 'asc';
          match = true;
          break;
    }
  }
  return field;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

array.map() doesn't let you exit the loop while it is in progress. So I think a for loop might work better here.

However, you cannot break a loop from inside a switch without using a temporary variable. It is easier if you can avoid using a switch:

```
for (const field of this.columns) {
  if (field.name == "creationTime" || field.name == "priority" || field.name == "completionTime") {
    field.sort = "asc";
    break; // Exit the loop after first match
  }
}
```